# Android studio="INTEL VT NOT FOUND "

Tags: android

Iam working on android studio but its keep giving error message "INTEL VT NOT FOUND" but my laptop does not support virtualization!!

Is there any other way to work on android studio????

Or any solution on how this error message can be skipped?

Currently my system specs are:

- Intel core duo processor.
- 4 gb ram.
- windows 10-64bits

Comment: If you don't have virtualization, you can't run the emulator... No way around that

Comment: But there are emulators that don't need virtualization - not used it myself but many people have used Genymotion

Comment: Genymotion runs in VirtualBox, which, yes, requires virtualization

Comment: Genymotion doesn't require Intel HAXM. I think that's where you're confused. You're more than welcome to try it, though

Comment: Then can i use eclipse to develop android for small period until i get new machine? And does eclipse support new android version?

Comment: to develop Android applications you don't need to change the IDE, you can still use Android Studio to develop, Android Studio does not requires virtualization but the emulator does, where/when does the message appear ??

Comment: When i run my first programme...

Comment: Personally, I'd say go buy a computer at least with an i3. If you really want build reasonable programs and emulate them, then an i5 and 8gb of RAM. Alternatively, run the code on an Android device

Comment: Thnx for the help... ☺